# /dev/sda file is not showing in bootloader installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, software-installation, gparted

In this image while installation of Ubuntu it's not showing the `/dev/sda` option which is my actual hard disk and where I have unallocated memory for Ubuntu.

[image: So in this image while installation of ubuntu its not showing me /dev/sda option which is my actual hardisak and where i have unallocated memory for ubuntu]

In this image I tried GParted in Ubuntu and my Ubuntu is detecting `/dev/sda`, but while installing Ubuntu it's not showing it.

[image: In this image i tried the gparted thing in ubuntu command prompt and my ubuntu is detecting /dev/sda but while installation its not showing it]

And by the way i have set sata mode to AHCI

Comment: Please be specific with details; you mention Ubuntu (which has numerous products & releases, and for some even ISO/installer choices), but don't provide clues as to which Ubuntu product, nor which Ubuntu release (and if a release that has different installers available for the same product, which one you opted to use). Just tell us & don't make us guess. Is your *sda* disk *clean* (ie. no hibernated system on it, which includes no *fastboot* option being used; as such partition(s) & drives can be ignored by some installers)

Comment: Is Microsoft Fast Start up (hibernation flag) or bitlocker on? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation